# Selenium remoteWebDriver (& SauceLabs) Firefox moseMoveTo action exception

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, saucelabs, remotewebdriver

While performing a simple hover test on Firefox through Selenium (3.4.0) with Python bindings (3.4.3) using any of the available OS in SauceLabs (except Linux, for which the latest available Firefox version is too old), by performing the following ActionChain:

```
hover = ActionChains(driver)
hover.move_to_element(elm_Men_Menu).perform()
```

It throws the following error:

Taceback:

```
File [...] in testHover
hover.perform()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
action()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 290, in <lambda>
                                                                                                              Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: mouseMoveTo
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'itako44164.prod.miso', ip: '[...]', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Stacktrace:
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode (AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:220)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode (AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute (HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute (DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute (RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove (RemoteMouse.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.internal.EventFiringMouse.mouseMove (EventFiringMouse.java:58)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.MouseMoveToLocation.call (MouseMoveToLocation.java:59)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.MouseMoveToLocation.call (MouseMoveToLocation.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Locally it works perfectly. I'm, using geckodriver 0.17.0 and Selenium 3.4.3 (edited). This was a previously reported error in Selenium, but it was solved for Selenium 3.x and geckodriver 0.15.0 (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285). For the SauceLabs test I am using Selenium 3.4.0 (as can be seen in the error report) and in SauceLabs documentation, for Firefox 53 and higher versions, geckodriver 0.16.0 is used (https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options#TestConfigurationOptions-SeleniumVersion), which, in principle, should support the move_to_element() action.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there a way to specify the geckodriver version? By now, the desired capabilities look like this:

```
desired_cap = {
  'platform':"Mac OS X 10.12",
  'browserName':"firefox",
  'version':"54",
  'seleniumVersion':"3.4.0",
}
```

**Edit 1**: I did not mention it, but it is working with both Chrome and IE11

**Edit 2**: The same problem occurs when executing the code locally with the selenium standalone server (3.4.0) in Linux. The geckodriver version is 0.17.0. Exact same traceback except for `System info: host:`

Comment: Quick question, selenium 3.4.0 version that you mentioned is the version of your local python bindings or selenium server used locally? For me some of the commands in actions class fail in local setup (setup: gecko 0.16, selenium server 3.4.0 and python binding 3.4.0) if i remove server from my local setup i.e do not use remotewebdriver then commands in actions class works.

Comment: It is the version of my local python bindings  (in fact, it is wrong, it is the 3.4.3, corrected in the post). In fact, locally I am not using the remotewebdriver, thus this might be the cause of this behavior. Have you reported those errors to Selenium? Are they related to the moveTo actions? (I will check it now)

Comment: Nope, I didn&#39;t get a chance to deep dive into it so didn&#39;t report it yet. Yes moveTo is affected as far as I can remember. Did you try it?

Comment: The same error comes up when executing the test locally with remoteWebDriver. I will edit the post, since it is a problem with Selenium remoteWebDriver, not SauceLabs itself

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments @Sanket Parlikar, they have enabled us to get to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Selenium was already aware of this problem:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4008

It has already been solved and will be available in the 3.5 version:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808#issuecomment-311105917

By now it can be solved cloning the master repository, building yourself the selenium server and starting the nodes with the `-enablePassThrough` flag